# node-red-dashboard - Chaining date selection from date-picker

Tags: dashboard, node-red

I have to invoke an API based on `start_date`, `end_date` and `report_type`. I know that the date picker does not support time selection which is unfortunate. However, I would like to use the widgets in my dashboard with the following constraints:

1. Do not enable `end_date` picker unless `start_date` picker selection is done.
2. `start_date` shouldn't be greater than current date.
3. `end_date` shouldn't be less than current date.
4. Enable drop-down for `report_type` only when `start_date` and `end_date` have been selected.

I have tried some variations of passing the selected value on to next node in flow, adding an object in `msg.payload` via a function node, etc. But, I can't seem to get the intended behavior. Worse, in one such attempt, I saw `end_date` defaulting to Unix epoch (Jan 1, 1970)!

Any suggestions on how to use time in date picker and 'chain' them as described above?